# Mode con Invalid parameter

Tags: batch-file

So I am working on a simple batch program, and when it starts up I want the window to be small, and then grow larger to fill a large portion of the screen. So far this is what I have:

```
@echo off
for /l %%I in (1,2,90) do (
set /a lines=%%I / 2
mode con cols=%%I
mode con lines=%lines%
)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
exit
```

Before this I had improvised a 'for' loop by with 'if' and 'goto' statements, and it worked fine, although it didn't look very nice (it was **very** jumpy). Here's my old code:

```
@echo off set /a y=14
set /a x=23
:start
mode con lines=%y%
mode con cols=%x%
if %x% geq 90 (
goto end
) else (
set /a x=%y% * 3
set /a y=%y% + 4
goto start
)
:end
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
exit
```

But when I run my ***new*** code the `mode con cols=%%I` works, but the `mode con lines=%lines%` gives me the error "Invalid parameter - lines=". Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing variables in a loop you need to use `delayed expansion` and then refer to variables as `!lines!` with the !variable! syntax.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```